# List on different websites looks different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I have a problem and I don’t understand it.

On one domain I got the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example2 ul').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if(href) {
         alert(href);
         return false;
         window.location = href;
       }
    });
});
```

```css
table#example2 {
 border-collapse: collapse; 
}
ul:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
ul:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #fff;
}
#example2 ul:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
}
#example2 li {
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: -30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#example2 ul:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
#example2 ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;height:150px;border: 2px solid grey;">
  <ul id="example2" style="width:100%">
      <ul>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a></li>
        <li>BBBBBBBBBBB</li>
        <li>CCCCCC</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a></li>
        <li>BBBBBBBBBBB</li>
        <li>CCCCCC</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a></li>
        <li>BBBBBBBBBBB</li>
        <li>CCCCCC</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Works perfect. And looks like:
[image]

But If I now want to use this on another domain – I copy and paste it – but it doesn’t work. Even no hover-effect.
It looks like this:

[image]
Want is the problem? It seems like my css requirements are overridden by an “user agent stylesheet”.
What does that mean and how can I fix it?

[image]

How can I define that only the li and ul of the list (table) will be modified by the css commands and not the uls and lis of the whole site? Hope someone can helf me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery included

Comment: The user agent style is applied because there is nothing else to apply. Now check your console, i guess your path to files (jq/css) are wrong...

Comment: Your stylesheet is not working on your html, make sure that you include it at the top of your page.

Comment: You have some invalid markup also. You have `<ul id="example2">` with no closing tag and with a another immediate `<ul>` nested inside. You should wrap it in a `<li />`

Comment: I insert the css-commands inside the wordpress page itself directly on top. Inside the wordpress header.php I added:  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalise.css"/>
<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script> But It still looks the same :( and jQuery hover-effect is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

When you say different "domains", do you mean like "site1.com" and "site2.com", if so, make sure the scripts you are including support cross domain requests (CORS).

The reason you are seeing the `box-sizing` styles crossed out, is because chrome supports the unprefixed property, so it ignores the vendor prefixed properties.

If you are experiencing issues with pages looking different across browsers, insert a reset or normalise stylesheet before your custom css, this will make all styles the same across different browsers. One of the most popular resources is https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/. Also, make sure that your HTML is valid using the W3C validator, some browsers will handle invalid code gracefully, others will not.

Comment: Yes I copied it from a.com to b.com. The script is/ should be just a simple opening a link by clicking a row. But I wonder why it works on the one wordpress side but not on the other - even if I just copy. What is a user agent stylesheet?

Comment: As in Chrome has default styles for a site, as does Firefox and Internet Explorer etc. A reset or normalise stylesheet makes these styles consistent across browsers.